# Serializing tasks using a Memory Mapped File

Tags: c#, ipc, shared-memory

I have a bunch of incoming web requests which I need to serialize and process one after each other. I cannot process more than one at a time. My current solution is to run a tool which can be accessed by a Web API using a Memory Mapped File acting as shared memory. I also need a Mutex to allow exclusive access to the shared memory. An event will be used to signal that a task was added.
So, basically we have there a multiple producers and one consumer. What follows is my first solution. Could someone tell whether or not there are some sort of race conditions or any other problems:

```
MemoryMappedFile MMF = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("Task_Queue", 5000);
MemoryMappedViewAccessor MMF_Accessor = MMF.CreateViewAccessor();

bool Mutex_Created = false;
Mutex Mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(false, "Mutex", out Mutex_Created);

if(Mutex_Created==false)
{
    // bad error

    return;
}

EventWaitHandle EWH = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);

Random Rand = new Random();


// Consumer
// work on the Tasks
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        // wait until a task has been added
        EWH.WaitOne();

        // get exclusive access to read in task
        Mutex.WaitOne();

        byte[] Buffer = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(new string(' ', 5000));
        MMF_Accessor.ReadArray(0, Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);

        int Position = 0;
        foreach (var b in Buffer) { if (b == 0) break; Position++; }

        string Message = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < Position; ++i)
        {
            Message += (char)Buffer[i];
        }


        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Message) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Message);
        }

        Mutex.ReleaseMutex();

        EWH.Reset();
    }
});



// Producer
// via a web request
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        if(EWH.WaitOne(0))
        {
            // consumer must take in the task first

            // wait a bit and then try again
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            break;
        }

        // wait until we access Shared Memory and claim it when we can
        Mutex.WaitOne();

        string Request = "Task 1 ";

        byte[] Buffer = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Request);
        Buffer[Buffer.Length - 1] = 0;

        MMF_Accessor.WriteArray(0, Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);

        // Signal that a tasks has been added to shared memory
        EWH.Set();

        // release the mutex so that others can use the shared memory
        Mutex.ReleaseMutex();

        Thread.Sleep(Rand.Next(10, 1000));
    }
});

// Producer
// via a web request
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        // wait until we access Shared Memory and claim it when we can
        Mutex.WaitOne();

        string Request = "Task 2 ";

        byte[] Buffer = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Request);
        Buffer[Buffer.Length - 1] = 0;

        MMF_Accessor.WriteArray(0, Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);

        // Signal that a tasks has been added to shared memory
        EWH.Set();

        // release the mutex so that others can use the shared memory
        Mutex.ReleaseMutex();

        Random r = new Random();
        Thread.Sleep(Rand.Next(10, 1000));
    }
});

while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
```

Please note the posted code is just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I want to understand your question better. Is it possible for you to add some diagrams?

Comment: As far as I understood, you can just use ConcurrentBag<Tasks>. You don't need MMF or worry about locks with ConcurrentBag.

Comment: The reason I think I need to use a Memory Mapped File is that the IIS worker is a separate process. So to add a task to the queue I need to use Interprocess Communication objects.

Comment: I posted a simple diagram here: http://imgur.com/dLMqzNY

Comment: Ok. I get the design. There is an better idea... Pipes. You will be saved from the limitation of MMF size. All the `producers` at Web Server side can write to the pipe which is being read by `consumer` at the other end. There is another even more general idea. I can elaborate that separately if you are interested. That idea will allow you to handle case when there are multiple `producers` in entirely different machines.

Comment: Thanks I will look into pipes. I know there is MSMQ but that seems a bit overkill for the my case. What I'm looking for is to have my synchronization correct and working.

Comment: Not MSMQ. It's TCP/IP that I was about to suggest.